# IIS 7.5 Application Initialization (Warmup) Module fails for web application not on port 80

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, warm-up

I'm using the Application Initialization module for IIS 7.5 on a Windows 2008 Server for a web site that's mapped to port 8080. After setting up the warmup module, I was able to get it to trigger `Application_Start()` in `Global.asax`, but not any of the pages I set up as initialization pages. When I added logging in `Application_BeginRequest()`, it showed that the warmup module was calling the pages on `localhost:80` instead of `localhost:8080`. I tried using `Server.TransferRequest` but that didn't work. Response.Redirect shouldn't work since these are dummy requests and there is no client to respond to the redirect. I was also wondering how any of this mattered at all, the web application was sent the request, as evidenced by triggerring `Application_BeginRequest()`, but then why didn't it proceed to render any of my pages? Logging on `Application_Error()` didn't show any errors on the requests to `localhost:80` pages.

Does anyone have an idea on what is causing this issue and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked this question on the [IIS Forums](http://forums.iis.net/p/1198067/2051114.aspx/1?Re%20Warmup%20not%20working%20for%20web%20application%20on%20port%20other%20than%2080), with no luck. I gave up on the issue and instead opted to warm up my pages my creating calls to my pages with `HttpWebResponse`. It works well and gives the added benefit of allowing me to give credentials to the warmup requests (my website uses ASP.NET impersonation) which initialization pages does not allow me to do.